# Changing Heroku app command when directly pushing docker image

Tags: haskell, docker, heroku, haskell-stack

I'm building a docker image locally and pushing it directly to Heroku using

```
docker tag <image> registry.heroku.com/<app>/<process-type>
docker push registry.heroku.com/<app>/<process-type>
```

as explained [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime). The reason for doing it this way is to be able to use `stack`'s docker integration, which seems promising. I set it up using the following stack.yaml:

```
resolver: lts-9.10

packages:
- '.'

extra-deps: []

flags: {}

extra-package-dbs: []

docker:
  enable: true

image:
  container:
    name: myimage
    base: haskell:8
```

as per [these docs](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/yaml_configuration.md).

My question then, is how to change the run command of the Heroku app. At the moment the command is `ghci`, which I assume is the default from 
`haskell:8`. Since I'm not using the normal `git push heroku master` I don't have a Procfile. Any ideas?